# Corda: I can't use binary streaming from the web UI to attach a pdf (file) to Corda node

Tags: corda

We are trying to upload a pdf as an attachment to the corda transaction using binary streaming. in fact we got our inspiration from here (https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-M13.0/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/Utils.kt) check out fun sizedInputStreamAndHash(). Are there any other suggestions what we could try?

The following is a snippet of how we wrote for binary streaming in the API:

```
    logger.debug(numOfClearBytes)
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ZipOutputStream(baos).use({ zos ->
        val arraySize = numOfClearBytes.toByteArray().size
        val bytes = numOfClearBytes.toByteArray()
        val n = (numOfClearBytes.toByteArray().size - 1) / arraySize + 1 // same as Math.ceil(numOfExpectedBytes/arraySize).
        zos.setLevel(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION)
        zos.putNextEntry(ZipEntry("z"))
        for (i in 0 until n) {
            zos.write(bytes, 0, arraySize)
        }
        zos.closeEntry()
    })
    val bytes = baos.toByteArray()
    val inputAndHash: InputStreamAndHash = InputStreamAndHash(ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), bytes.sha256())

    val attachmentId = services.uploadAttachment(inputAndHash.inputStream)

    val flowHandle = services.startTrackedFlow(::Payer, exchangeAmount, otherParty, attachmentId)

    val attachmentId = services.uploadAttachment(inputAndHash.inputStream)

    val flowHandle = services.startTrackedFlow(::Payer, exchangeAmount, otherParty, attachmentId)
```

Comment: And what went wrong? Was there an error message?

Comment: Howdy Joel! Its not so much on the problem of Corda, but i guess the library to use to get the web API working. We used 'import org.glassfish.jersey.media' to our project and got an error due to the corda didn’t register MultiPartFeature.class when it starts the webserver. Without that we can't use @FormDataParam in the api for MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA

Answer (score 0):

To upload an attachment to the node via HTTP using the built-in webserver, you have to hit the `/upload/attachment` endpoint. This endpoint is provided by the node by default - you do not have to add it youself. See https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V1/webserver/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/webserver/servlets/DataUploadServlet.kt.

If you send an attachment to this endpoint, it will be uploaded to the node and the endpoint will return the hash of the file on the node.

You can then use either `CordaRPCOps.openAttachment` or `ServiceHub.attachments.openAttachment` to retrieve the attachment as an input stream using its hash. You can then process it as you see fit (either in a web endpoint or in a flow).

To see an example CorDapp that uses a HTTP endpoint to upload an attachment, see the Blacklist sample here: https://github.com/corda/samples (details in the readme).

Comment: Howdy Joel! I am looking at the code. Where is this /upload/attachment endpoint? Is there a script running because it clearly responds with a hash of the jar/zip file.

Comment: We need the file to be made through the webserver, so we can parse for information before we put it as attachment in the same Tx. Currently we have a text file and a pdf file of the actual contract. The text we can parse, and zip up before we put into the tx at the api. However we are sort of stuck in getting the Pdf to zip together with text at the api. 

Anyway I will take a look to see we what more we can try.

Comment: Updated my answer above.